# Importing CocoaLumberjack with Carthage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, carthage, cocoalumberjack

I am trying to import CocoaLumberjack into my project, but I always get something like

> 'CocoaLumberjack.h' file not found.

It is an Xcode 8 project with Objective-C and Carthage (instead of Pods). On the [git page](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) it says use version 3.2.0 for Xcode 8 and Swift 3. Is this the right version for me when I don't use Swift? Should I stick with 2.2.0? Right now I am testing with 3.2.0. 2.2.0 had issues building...

I added `git "https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.git" "3.2.0"` or `github "CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack" "3.2.0"`

to the Cartfile, ran `carthage update`, the commands run through and they said somehting like

> Checking out CocoaLumberjack at "3.2.0"

...

> "CocoaLumberjack-iOS" in Lumberjack.xcworkspace Building scheme
>
> "CocoaLumberjackSwift-iOS" in Lumberjack.xcworkspace

When it's done I open my Project-Prefix.pch and try to set some macros but I fail importing the plugin. I tried:

```
#import "CocoaLumberjack"
#import "<CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>"
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
#import "CocoaLumberjack.h"
@import CocoaLumberjack;
@import "CocoaLumberjack"
```

But they all fail with some kind of

> Could not build module 'CocoaLumberjack'

or

> '' file not found

errors.

How do I import this correctly? Is there any clue in the project hierarchy where I can see whether adding it with Carthage worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolving the dependencies you do `carthage update`, but after this do you run `carthage build`? Then after the building process, add the framework `CocoaLumberjack.framework` (you can find it in the folder `Carthage/Build/iOS`) to your main project

---

moreover please be sure to have this configuration:
[image]

finally you should be able to import the library in this way:

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
```

usage example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just managed to do this but this is the clearest and most complete answer I got so far.